# How to define very specific filter for update method in PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a very specific query in my project that returns me the the document with the lowest date:

```
   data = collection.find({'status': 'to_be_posted'}).sort('creation_date', pymongo.ASCENDING).limit(1)[0]
```

But now I have an issue with updating documents matching this query. Something like that simply doesn't work:

```
collection.update( { 'status' : 'to_be_posted' },
           { '$set' : {
               'status' : 'posted'
           },
           { array_filters: [{ $group : { _id: null, max: { $max : "$creation_date" }}}]
           } } )
```

...or smth like that:

```
collection.update( {'status': 'to_be_posted'}.sort('creation_date', pymongo.ASCENDING).limit(1),
           { '$set' : {
               'status' : 'posted'
           } } )
```

I need to update a document with the lowest date and "to_be_posted" status to "posted" status.
I've got no idea how to write a correct query filter for such update method. What operators should I use? Can I use Query Modifiers?

Comment: You can try the findAndModify operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/#db.collection.findAndModify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one_and_update](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-python-driver/blob/3.7.1/pymongo/collection.py#L2939) can be used to perform a find and update query altogether.

> **Parameters**
>
> `filter`: A query that matches the document to update.
>
> `update`: The update operations to apply.
>
> `projection` (optional): A list of field names that should be
>   returned in the result document or a mapping specifying the fields
>   to include or exclude. If `projection` is a list "_id" will
>   always be returned. Use a dict to exclude fields from
>   the result (e.g. projection={'_id': False}).
>
> `sort` (optional): a list of (key, direction) pairs
>   specifying the sort order for the query. If multiple documents
>   match the query, they are sorted and the first is updated.
>
> `upsert` (optional): When `True`, inserts a new document if no
>   document matches the query. Defaults to `False`.
>
> `return_document`: If
>   :attr:`ReturnDocument.BEFORE` (the default),
>   returns the original document before it was updated, or `None`
>   if no document matches. If
>   :attr:`ReturnDocument.AFTER`, returns the updated
>   or inserted document.
>
> `array_filters` (optional): A list of filters specifying which
>   array elements an update should apply. Requires MongoDB 3.6+.
>
> `session` (optional): a
>   :class:`~pymongo.client_session.ClientSession`.
>
> `**kwargs` (optional): additional command arguments can be passed
>   as keyword arguments (for example maxTimeMS can be used with
>   recent server versions).

```
import pymongo
from pymongo.collection import ReturnDocument

filter = {'status': 'to_be_posted'}
update = {'$set': {'status' : 'posted'}}
sort = [('creation_date', pymongo.ASCENDING)]
updated_doc = collection.find_one_and_update(
                  filter, update, sort=sort, 
                  return_document=ReturnDocument.AFTER
              )
```